# How to execute raw SQL on DB (not on specific table)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, ormlite

I use PostgreSQL and ORMlite in my application, that is runned on a Windows server.  Before creating all the tables, I need to verify if the database is existing in Postgres, and if not I have to create it.

I already have my SQL Raw:

- check if existing: 
  `final String SQL = "SELECT 1 from pg_database WHERE datname='MY_NOME_DB' ;";`
- create it (if not existing):  
  `String SQL= "CREATE DATABASE MY_NOME_DB ; " ;`

QUESTION: How to exec that using ORMLite?
I know that to exec a raw SQL I can use:

```
myDAO.executeRaw(SQL);
```

but here it is not on a specific table, so I cannot use it because I cannot create myDAO.

Comment: I don't know about postgresql or ormlite but for MySQL I could create a connection _without specifying the database to use_, then issue a `SHOW databases LIKE 'MY_NOME_DB'` command.

Comment: `Before to create all the tables, I need to verify if the database is existing in PostSql, and if not I have to create it.` Bad approach. Just create them. If it fails, either the table already existed, or you are not allowed to create them. Same for the database: just try connect to it. if that fails ...

Comment: That is a horrible idea because it means your application has to connect to the server using a superuser account. This is not something you should do.

Comment: NO problem if I use superuser inside app; the java app and the Database are on the same server, and the application is the only one that access to the DB. So username and password are hidden inside the java code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also agree that it is not good practice.
But your intent is possible in ormLite.
You can use raw query any DAO.  DAO is not strictly bounded in table.

Refer my sample codes.

`sqls.xml`  : it contains raw query.  You can define any raw query.

```
<item name="sql_login" type="string">
    SELECT AdminPubTBL.*
    FROM PDARunPubTBL
    JOIN AdminPubTBL ON PDARunPubTBL.AdminSeqNo = AdminPubTBL.AdminSeqNo
    .....
      AND AdminPubTBL.AdminPwd = \'@adminPwd\' LIMIT 1
</item>
```

`adminDao.java`

```
public interface AdminDao {
    Admin login(int pdaSeqNo, int sectionSeqNo, String adminId, String adminPwd, String corpCode);
```

`adminDaoOrmLite.java` : You can use `queryRaw` and return to any Java object.

```
public class AdminDaoOrmLite implements AdminDao {
    @Nullable
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;
    @Nullable
    private Dao<Admin, Integer> adminDao = null;
    public Admin login(int pdaSeqNo, int sectionSeqNo, @NonNull String adminId, String adminPwd, String corpCode) {
        String sql = context.getResources().getString(R.string.sql_login)
                .replace("@pdaSeqNo", String.valueOf(pdaSeqNo))
                .replace("@sectionSeqNo", String.valueOf(sectionSeqNo))
                .replace("@adminId", adminId)
                .replace("@adminPwd", hashedPassword(adminPwd,corpCode));
        try {
            return adminDao.queryRaw(sql, adminDao.getRawRowMapper()).getFirstResult();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }
```

So if you want to want raw query.  Make common DAO, then execute `.queryRaw()`

Comment: Hi, what is Admin? It is a class of Android maybe? I'm not on Android, I'm on PC, so also databaseHelper is not available...

Comment: The main difference of pc and android is where it uses jdbc or databasehelper.  Usage of DAO is same. You can just use jdbc connection fro DAO.   ormlite can execute any raw sql  from any DAO.  But it is not recomended.

Comment: If you want to just `create table if not exist`, you can choose  `connection.executeStatement(raw)` instead DAO.  You can find examples in https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource

Comment: FInal solution: at the end of the story I created a connection by jdcb driver and I exec 'connection.executeStatement(raw)'

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked for it, but there might be other (better) solutions other than yours.

Generally, it is not a good approach to couple the application and the infrastructure. Your PostgreSql is part of your infrastructure and your application should not care whether your infrastructure is set.

A better approach would consist in splitting your infrastructure definition, probably using a simple Bash script or (ideally) something like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) and **don't couple** your application from your infrastructure.